# Disabling autoplay in FB video ads getting called on but still auto playing - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I have just embedded video ads from facebook and i can't get them to stop autoPlaying.
According to the documentation there is a property to disable AutoPlay, which i added, it's getting called on but not working. 
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBMediaView/)
I tried setting it to no in right after initializing the view and also tried right after adding it as a subview. 
In both cases when i put a break point i see that the value of the property changes to NO, but by the time the ad itself actually show it autoplays again!
Anyone had the pleasure of working with this?

This is how i tried:

- (void)nativeAdDidLoad:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd {
  adCoverMediaView = [[FBMediaView alloc] initWithNativeAd:nativeAd];
  [adCoverMediaView setNativeAd:nativeAd];
  [adCoverMediaView setAutoplayEnabled:NO];

//after this didn't work i tried adding it here: (later in the same method)

```
    [legacyAdView addSubview:adCoverMediaView];
[adCoverMediaView setAutoplayEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Awesome; looking at the docs, the property is described like this:  "Enables or disables autoplay **for some types of media**." (emphasis mine).  Maybe the format/media type of your ads aren't supported?

Comment: @fullofsquirrels it doesn't seem to define which though, and given that this is the view that controls the video ads it seems logical to me that it would be supported. However, i couldn't find any way to really verify this. Do you maybe know?

Comment: Agreed, but it's not clear to me (having never used the Facebook APIs) exactly what "types of media" might be supported; in what format have you embedded your video ads?  Are they raw H.264/MPEG-4 assets, live HTTP streams, Vimeo/Vine/YouTube assets, or something else?  Also, independent of that, could you perhaps set the `autoplayEnabled` property inside the `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear` methods of your view's containing view controller?

Comment: @fullofsquirrels thanks you so much for trying to help! I really appreciate it, but i need someone who has worked with facebook audience network before.. its implementation is different and doesn't necessarily  work with the regular view controller

Comment: @Einat Did you ever found a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Lowip at the time we decided to drop it and i haven't worked with it since so i don't know if they added support.. sorry, and good luck!

Comment: @Einat No problem! It seems that they modified this property to be readonly in the latest version (FBAudienceNetwork 4.99.0)